# Forcing a window to be scaled on high DPI displays

Tags: windows-10

The problem with 4k displays is that a lot of older programs weren't designed for them, and they don't scale. This results in having a tiny window, which is particularly bad for older games.

I recently found a post online explaining how to force the program to scale, specifically by setting "PreferExternalManifest" in the registry, then pasting the following into "EXEname.manifest":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly
 xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
 manifestVersion="1.0"
 xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
       type="win32"
       name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
       version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"
       publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
       language="*">
      </assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
       type="win32"
       name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
       version="9.0.21022.8"
       processorArchitecture="amd64"
       publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
      </assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
         level="asInvoker"
         uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware
       xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
        false
      </ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

I'd like to know how exactly this works, and whether or not it's possible to force a window to scale even bigger (it's a *really* old game :p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `PreferExternalManifest` settings enabled the manifest file that is included in the exe is ignored. Now the self created manifest is used. Here this line

```
<ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware
       xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
        false
</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
```

tells Windows that the program is not DPI aware and Windows will apply DPI virtualization (blurry bitmap scaling).

An easier way is to enable a registry setting

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\PROGRAMNAME.exe]
"dpiAwareness"=dword:00000000
```

for each program you want to "fix".

Comment: Would that not apply to all executables having that filename anywhere on the system? While generally speaking EXE files tend to be unique, there's nothing requiring that so long as they're in different folders, but this registry key seems like it will affect any EXE with that filename. That aside, any word on how to override the scaling further? For instance, applying an alternative DPI to that program so it scales bigger?

Comment: yes, that would apply to all exe with that name.

Comment: For the particular app I'm looking at (Unity.exe) your second solution was the only one I found that worked for me, and it should be very robust against multiple installs and reinstalls. Thank you so much!